# How to check whether two pixels are directly connected with foreground pixels in an binary image?

Tags: image, image-processing

I have two binary images, A and B. Image B is made from some key points taken from image A. Now I have to edge connect these key points in image B, such that for every pair of key points in B there is an edge if these two key points are directly connected (by a chain of foreground pixels) in original Image A. How can I do this?

Comment: You should extract the connectivity graph from image A by following every edge from every key point.

Comment: How about labeling image A (connected component analysis), then finding the label corresponding to each key point, and drawing lines between each pair of key points that have the same label?

Comment: Yves Daoust, what do we mean by connectivity graph.If u can explain bit, that will help.

Comment: Cris Luengo, just like that////     if labeledImage(rc(i,1), rc(i,2)) == labeledImage(rc(j,1), rc(j,2))/// .